# Не запускается виртуальная машина с Ubuntu на VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, виртуальная-машина

Я написал программу под Android на Python и Kivy, и решил его собрать. Но для сборки требуется Linux и я решил установить виртуальную машину что-бы собрать файл и за одно попробовать поработать с Ubuntu... Установив VB я создал виртуальную машину (см. рис. 2). Первый раз она запустилась без ошибок и на нее спокойно встал Ubuntu. Но на следующий день запустив машину я вижу такую ошибку (см. рис. 1):

*Рис. 1*

[image: Окно ошибки при запуске виртуальной машины]

Как и написано в ошибке я переустановил VB, но это не помогло. Я решил пересоздать саму виртуальную машину и все ровно происходит по тому же сценарию: удачный запуск -> установка Ubuntu -> выключение виртуальной машины -> запуск -> ошибка. Так же я совсем недавно переустанавливал свой Windows 10, и менял оперативку вместе с системным диском (с ними не каких проблем)... У меня включен Hyper-V и виртуализация в BIOS.

*Рис. 2*

[image: Конфигурация виртуальной машины и ошибка в окне уведомлений]

Подскажите как исправить эту ошибку, заранее благодарен)

Comment: попробуте поставить paravirt. interface `Hyper-V`

Comment: Не помогло( та же самая ошибка...

Comment: у VB от обновления к обновлению бывают странности, я обычно пользуюсь vmware player

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую VMWare

Comment: А паравиртуализацию на дефолтную поставить?

Comment: пробовал все варианты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил эту проблему проведя полную проверку ПК от вирусов (возможно и это помогло, т.к. Windows странно вел себя). И отключив виртуализацию Hyper-V в Windows... Что странно